# Apache Superset Json column in SQL Lab result section showing in single Quotes in version 2.1.0

Tags: json, jsonb, apache-superset

Recently we updated our Apache superset to **version 2.1.0**. I noticed in SQL Lab, after we hit an sql query, in result section, the json column is showing **key-value pair in "single Quotes**" which in previous version use to show in **"double quotes"**.

The structure of my DB is something like this:

```
create table abc
(
  source_id varchar(255) not null,
  json jsonb,
  created_at timestampz not null,
  updated_at timestampz not null,
  constraint pk_source_id primary key(source_id)
);
```

The problem with single quotes is that, i can not copy and use that json, as it is not proper json. And I checked directly **in my DB** with sql command on my server and it is storing that column value in **double quotes**.

So wondering **if this is bug** in new version or **if there is some setting** which I can enable so that it shows my json key-value within "double Quotes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like new behaviour for this version. But the way around to get proper output in column is to use this sql query:

```
select json::TEXT from abc;
```

This vl give output in proper json format.